# SpriteKit positioning of nodes

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm building a game, and I am trying to replace an enemy node with a coin node after shooting him.

Everything works fine until I add a physics body to the coin, at which point the coin gets positioned wherever the main character is instead of where the enemy was. However, if the main character's x position is less than 284 pixels from the left or right edge of the scene, the coin gets added to the scene at x 284 (or -284 if on the right).

If I comment out this line: `self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height)];` in Coin.m, then the coin is positioned where it's supposed to be, but then the character can't interact with it.

Here's a snippet of the code. I use basically the same technique to add lasers to the scene, but have no issue with those.

Inside of MyScene.m:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    ...
    Coin *coin = [[Coin alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"coin"];
    coin.xScale = 0;
    coin.yScale = 0;
    [_charactersLayer addChild:coin];
    coin.position = enemyPosition;
    [coin runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:.4], [SKAction scaleTo:1.0 duration:0.5]]]];
```

Inside the Coin class:

```
@implementation Coin

- (instancetype)initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name
{
    if (self = [super initWithImageNamed:name]) {
        self.name = @"coin";
        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height)];
        self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = PCToolCategory;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

If someone could point out whether I'm doing something wrong, or offer a workaround, it would be appreciated.

Comment: try setting position before creating the physics body

Comment: OK, so if I create the physics body in MyScene and move it out of the Coin.m init method, I get a runtime error on the line that instantiates the physics body... `malloc: *** error for object 0x1804dd90: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`.... Here's the line of code: `coin.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(coin.size.width, coin.size.height)];`... Doesn't matter if that line is before or after the line where I set the position or where I add it to the scene.